# Finding unique Values in two arrays - Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, unique

I have two arrays @results and @results2 that between them have masses of numbers. e.g (12345678 182937439 18329741 etc)

In both arrays if I combined them I could get duplication which I do not want. I would like to compare the two arrays, keep the unique values and print them one after the other.

Comment: Type `perldoc -q duplicate` at your command prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So dedupe the arrays. This code borrowed from [`List::MoreUtils`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aMoreUtils) `uniq` function:

```
sub uniq {
    my %seen;
    grep { !$seen{$_}++ } @_;
}

my @unique = uniq(@results, @results2);
```

Comment: Using a hash for numeric values can be a bit iffy, especially if the values are floating point. `200`, `0200`, `200.0`, and `2E2`, amongst many others, could all represent the same value. Even if the values are guaranteed to be integers it may be best to apply `map { sprintf '%d', $_ } @data` to make everything uniform.

Comment: Note that you should use `uniq` from [List::MoreUtils](http://p3rl.org/List::MorUtils "perldoc List::MorUtils") if possible because it has an XS version which is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you think "unique" think "hash"

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @a = qw(1 2 3);
my @b = qw(3 4 5);

my %x = map { $_ => 1 } @a, @b;

print join ", ", keys %x; # 4, 1, 3, 2, 5
```